# Ruby find and replace around a simple pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, text-processing, string-matching

I have some input text, that could contain some patterns like

```
bla bla bla ###FOO WORLD### bla bla bla
bla bla bla ###FOO BOB###, ###FOO ALICE###bla bla bla
```

I want to process this and output

```
bla bla bla HELLO WORLD bla bla bla
bla bla bla HELLO BOB, HELLO ALICEbla bla bla
```

This is a bit more than find and replace because I want to preserve the content between the ### markers. I understand this should be easy with a regular expression... But I'm very rusty with regexes beyond anything but simple pattern matching.

What is the best way do do this? Do I need a regular expression object. Or does the string class have methods better suited to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "bla bla bla ###FO­O BOB##­#, ###FO­O ALICE­###bla bla bla"
s.gsub(/###F­OO (.*?)­###/, 'HELL­O \1')
# => bla bla bla HELLO BOB, HELLO ALICEbla bla bla
```

The `F­OO (.*?)` captures the text after `FOO`, and the `gsub` replaces the matching text with `HELLO` followed by the capture text.

Answer (score 0):

@Baldrick is Prefectly correct just another answer using blocks :)

```
 a.gsub(/###FOO (.*?)###/) do
     "HELLO " + $1
 end
```